# Consuming a HTTPS service in a c# class library using Com and Delphi

Tags: c#, web-services, delphi, com, delphi-xe5

I have a https web service I want to consume.

In C# I can achieve this in about 10ish lines of code.

In Delphi XE5 It's a major headache and a mess of certificate stores and encryption. I need to be able to consume this in Delphi XE5.

My idea was to stick the (simple) call to the web service in a C# Class Library and then instantiate it via Delphi using `CreateOleObject`. The class library is `regasm library.dll /codebase` and `gacutil -i library.dll`

My problem seems to be that when consuming a web service from C#, it relies quite heavily on the endpoint and binding settings stored in the app.config file. Problem is, is because I'm using Delphi and COM this config file reading goes awry (I get the error: `Could not find endpoint element with name...` ).

I've tried various permutations of `MyDelphiTestApp.exe.config` and `library.dll.config` and they all seem to fail getting read (copy of the `app.config` file from the class library project that has the correct data in it). I've debugged the C# class library at runtime to see where it thinks the config file is and then made sure there was one there, but it still fails.

Can anyone give me solution or a push in the right direction?

Edit: 30th May.
Thanks for the help so far. My code currently stands at:

```
        var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100000);
        binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100000);
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10000;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 10000;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 10000;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 10000;

        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", false);
        store.Close();
        if (certs.Count <= 0)
            return "Could not find certificate";

        AddressHeader addressHeader1 = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("service1", "https://wibble.com/Service", 1);
        AddressHeader[] addressHeaders = new AddressHeader[1] { addressHeader1 };
        AddressHeaderCollection addressHeaderColl = new AddressHeaderCollection(addressHeaders);

        var epIdentity = new X509CertificateEndpointIdentity(certs[0]);
        EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://wibble.com/Service/DataService.svc"), epIdentity, addressHeaderColl);

        AiropsScheduleDataServiceClient client = new AiropsScheduleDataServiceClient(binding, remoteAddress);


        var defaultCredentials = client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
        client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(defaultCredentials); //remove the default credentials

        var loginCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
        loginCredentials.UserName.UserName = Username;
        loginCredentials.UserName.Password = Password;

        client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(loginCredentials); //Add new credential to the proxy

        ExportScheduleDataRequest request = new ExportScheduleDataRequest();
        ExportScheduleDataResponse response = client.ExportScheduleData(request);
```

...but this is giving me a Delphi client error of

"Secure channel cannot be opened because security negotiation with the remote endpoint has failed. This may be due to absent or incorrectly specified EndpointIdentity in the EndpointAddress used to create the channel. Please verify the EndpointIdentity specified or implied by the EndpointAddress correctly identifies the remote endpoint"

I'm lost again.

Comment: Why are you not using one of the existing SOAP client toolkits for Delphi? They create the Delphi wrapper code automatically.

Comment: @mjn "In Delphi XE5 It's a major headache and a mess of certificate stores and encryption"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what headaches you are getting with XE5 but to answer your question you can do the following in your C# code to do the bindings through code rather than have them in the app.config file:

```
  var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
  binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100000);
  binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100000);
  binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10000;
  binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 10000;
  binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 10000;
  binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 10000;
  // Set the security mode
  binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
  var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:57102/MyService.svc");
  var myClient = new WebServiceclient(binding, endpoint);
```

You can change the values as you need and use a BasicHttpBinding or another if you want.

As these values are in code you can pass them directly through from your Delphi application.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I had something very similar to what you wrote.

Comment: @PaulEndersby You need to set the security mode as well. I have added that to my answer. Basically everything you normally set through your app.config for your secure connection would now need to be set through code.

Comment: Thanks @Graymatter for persisting with this. I thought that the constructor took the security mode as a constructor parameter and I have that set to `SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential`